# Direction flag d not found in PIC programming

Tags: pic

As a beginner in PIC programming I try to understand an existing and running code. In that code I find.

```
movf    c10m,w          ;Read 10th of min count
movwf   bcd_in          ;Set counter code here
```

**Where to find the destination flag d?**

I understand that data of c10m goes into w with movf.  The behaviour of movf depends on a destination flag d. But I can not find the whereabout of the flag and how to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

The direction bit is normally decided by the second operand.  This is described but not very clearly in the microchip manual (it uses FSR which is an indrection register).  The instruction means move file the contents of the file register.  If d=0, the destination is W; if d=1, it is the register itself.

The format of the command is

```
MOVF file,d
```

where d=0 or 1 but most assemblers will accept W in place of d.  Note that it does not check the contents of W.  It is not that complex.  It does not matter what is in W, it will get overwritten.

```
               ; d Before      After
               ;   W  TMR0 Z   W TMR0 Z
MOVF TMR0,W    ; 0 ??  25  ?   25 25  0
MOVF TMR0,W    ; 0 ??  00  ?   00 00  1
MOVF TMR0,0    ; 0 ??  25  ?   25 25  0  same as MOVF TMR0,W
MOVF TMR0,1    ; 1 ??  25  ?   ?? 25  0
MOVF TMR0,1    ; 1 ??  00  ?   ?? 00  1
```

Moving a file register to itself will cause the zero flag to be set if the value is zero.